# Replace class depending on event

Tags: javascript, jquery

If have a set of collapsible elements, in which I need to replace classes *left* and *right* depending on event *isCollapse*:

```
<div class="collapsible-set">
  <div class="collapsible">
      <h3>
        <a class="left">
           <span class="left"></span>
        </a>
      </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="collapsible">
      <h3>
        <a class="right">
           <span class="right"></span>
        </a>
      </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to toggle the classes. Is there an eaiser way to do this than what I came up with?

```
if (collapse) {
  $('.left').addClass('topLeft').removeClass('left');
  $('.right').addClass('topRight').removeClass('right');
  } else if (!collapse) {
    $('.topLeft').addClass('left').removeClass('topLeft');
    $('.topRight').addClass('right').removeClass('topRight');
    }
```

There must be an eaiser way to do this without writing so much code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at toogleClass http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```
$('.collapsible:eq(0)').find('a').toggleClass('topLeft').toggleClass('left');
$('.collapsible:eq(1)').find('a').toggleClass('topRight').toggleClass('right');
```

Comment: should be eq(0) shouldn't it?

Comment: By the way, you can shorten it: `.toggleClass("topLeft", "left");`

Comment: @Oleg G. - that sounds good! I'm still trying to fiddle my way with this solution.

Comment: @OlegG. the second attribute for the function is true or false so no idea if it works

Comment: got it. calling like this: .toggleClass("ui-corner-left", isCollapse ).toggleClass("ui-corner-tl", !isCollapse);

Comment: It works in toggling between two classes, but not really helpful in the current situation...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
$(".collapsible").find(".topLeft, .left").toggleClass("topLeft", collapse).toggleClass("left", !collapse);
$(".collapsible").find(".topRight, .right").toggleClass("topRight", collapse).toggleClass("right", !collapse);
```